# Backbone - embedded youtube iframe in _ template and zindex issue

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have iFrame in my template as following:

```
<iframe class="videoContainer" src="<%= url %>&html5=1" width="400" height="230" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have issues putting generated iFrames behinde the popup with zindex of 500;

here is class="videoContainer"

> .videoContainer {
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 30px;
>     left: 0;
>     bottom: 0;
>     z-index: 1;
>   }

Things that I've already tried:

> 1- putting wmode=transparent or wmode=Opaque in beginning of the url by the following code before iFrame

```
<% url = url.substring(0 , url.indexOf('?') + 1) + 'wmode=transparent&' +  url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1 , url.length); %>
```

as I could see iframe and resulting url was correct , but still having problem with overlay.

> 2- putting wmode=transparent or wmode=Opaque at the end of the url, after html5=1;

still no result,
can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/nejj/EkrQD/

Comment: well, apparently the issue was in the url, I just changed /v/ to /embed/ and solve the problem. Thanks